# Could not create process in borland compiler

Tags: c++, borland-c++

when i run the project(debug-> Run) it is giving an error in a pop up box having message **"Could not Create the process"**. The project is created using borland C++ 4.52.can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: From experience with other IDEs, Sometimes you need to re-build the project, sometimes you simply need to close and restart the IDE, other-times the IDE screws-up the project file and you need to create a new project and add the existing source-code/resources to it. Last time I used a Borland IDE was in the 90's, so take my advice with a grain of salt!

Comment: What system are you on? That compiler is now nearly 20 years old, back from when Windows 95 was brand new. Wouldn't it be an option to switch to another compiler, or do you have to deal with legacy code? Could it be your program is still compiled as 16-bit? That will not work on "newer" windows versions.

Comment: @Axel since he is running BC 4.52 IDE, then he is able to run 16-bit apps, as that IDE was 16-bit itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these instructions:

> Run Your Program
>
> From the Menu Bar: Debug-Run
>
> This will launch a window and run your program in it. After it finishes the window will go inactive and you will probably have to close it manually by clicking the 'x' icon in the upper right corner.
>
> If the present window is one not your source code window - for instance, it will probably be the Message window after compiling and/or linking the program - then you will get a **"Could not create process."** error. This is because you are trying to execute the contents of a window that doesn't contain a program. Select the source code window and try again.

Source: http://www.dragonwins.com/courses/ECE1021/STATIC/LESSONS/IntroToTurboC.htm#Run%20Your%20Program